# Trying to store an authentication token as a system variable in python but it returns None when printed

Tags: windows, python-3.x, powershell, authentication, environment-variables

I have an authentication token I'm trying to store as a system variable in Windows 10, I tried creating a new User variable called 'SLACK_BOT_USER_TOKEN' and a new system variable by the same name, set the value to my authentication code, and then run this code in python 3.6:

```
import os

print(os.getenv('PATH'))
print(os.getenv('SLACK_BOT_USER_TOKEN'))
```

which returns my PATH (expected) and 'None'. Why isn't it recognizing the new variable I created? I am using powershell to run the script as an administrator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Processes like CMD and PowerShell obtain a copy of the environment when being started. This copy isn't updated when you modify the original environment variables. You need to restart the process to get the updated values or modify the copied variables in addition to modifiying the variables in the system settings.

Demonstration:

```
PS C:\> echo $env:FOO
PS C:\> python
Python 3.3.2 (v3.3.2:d047928ae3f6, May 16 2013, 00:03:43) [MSC v.1600 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> print(os.getenv('FOO'))
None
>>> exit()
PS C:\> $env:FOO = 'bar'
PS C:\> echo $env:FOO
bar
PS C:\> python
Python 3.3.2 (v3.3.2:d047928ae3f6, May 16 2013, 00:03:43) [MSC v.1600 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> print(os.getenv('FOO'))
bar
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to reboot my computer to solve the problem.

Comment: If the variable is set via the GUI environment variable editor, then Explorer's environment should be updated already. You shouldn't have to reboot the system. However, you do have to restart Python (or cmd / PowerShell and then Python) from Explorer to see the updated environment.

Comment: I see, I probably just needed to reboot my shell then. Thanks for the clarification!